# NotificationCenter.Publisher VS PassThroughSubject

Tags: swift, combine

I have an object which I want to send throughout multiple listeners/subscribers, so I was checking out Combine and I saw 2 different kind of publishers, namely `NotificationCenter.Publisher` and `PassThroughSubject`. I am confused why anyone would use a `NotificationCenter.Publisher` over `PassThroughSubject`.

I came up with the code below, demonstrating both ways. To summarize:

- `NotificationCenter.Publisher` needs to have a `Notification.Name` static property
- Isn't really that typesafe (since I can post a different kind of object for the same `Notification.Name`/different publisher for the same `Notification.Name`)
- Posting a new value needs to be done on `NotificationCenter.default` (not the publisher itself)
- An explicit downcast to the used type in the `map` closure

In what scenarios someone will use `NotificationCenter.Publisher` over `PassThroughSubject`?

```
import UIKit
import Combine

let passThroughSubjectPublisher = PassthroughSubject<String, Never>()
let notificationCenterPublisher = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .name).map { $0.object as! String }

extension Notification.Name {
    static let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "someName")
}


class PassThroughSubjectPublisherSubscriber {
    init() {
        passThroughSubjectPublisher.sink { (_) in
            // Process
        }
    }
}

class NotificationCenterPublisherSubscriber {
    init() {
        notificationCenterPublisher.sink { (_) in
            // Process
        }
    }
}

class PassThroughSubjectPublisherSinker {
    init() {
        passThroughSubjectPublisher.send("Henlo!")
    }
}

class NotificationCenterPublisherSinker {
    init() {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .name, object: "Henlo!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have to use a 3rd party framework that uses NotificationCenter.

Comment: They would use NotificationCenter to be compatible with older iOS versions.

Comment: This is about NotificationCenter.Publisher which is only available on iOS versions 13.0 or higher, exactly the same as any other publisher

Answer (score 2):

`NotificationCenter` can be thought of as a first generation message passing system, while `Combine` is second generation. It has runtime overhead and requires casting the objects you can store in `Notification`s. Personally I would never use `NotificationCenter` when building an iOS 13 framework, but you do need to use it to access a lot of iOS notifications that are only published there. Basically in my personal projects I’m going to treat it as read only unless absolutely necessary.